# Libgdx android backbutton turn off sound?

Tags: android, libgdx

When i click on tablet backbutton game is finish. When i click start icon my game came back, but sound doesn't play. I know there are some problems with sounds and music in Libgdx on android. How to manage this problem?
For know my resume method is empty.

```
public class MyGdxGame extends Game {

MenuScreen menuScreen;
GameScreen gameScreen;
About gameOverScreen;

private AdsController adsController;

public MyGdxGame(AdsController adsController){
    this.adsController = adsController;}

public MyGdxGame(){}


@Override
public void create() {
    menuScreen = new MenuScreen(this);
    gameScreen = new GameScreen(this);
    gameOverScreen = new About(this);
    AssetsLoader.load();
    adsController.showBannerAd();
    setScreen(new MenuScreen(this));
}

@Override
public void dispose(){
    super.dispose();
    AssetsLoader.dispose();
}

public class AssetsLoader {
public static Texture texture, bg, ground, play;

static Music music = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("musicbackground.mp3"));


public static Sound soundPunch = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("Strong_Punch-Mike_Koenig-574430706.mp3"));

public static Sound soundSlide = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("slide.mp3"));

public static Sound soundJump = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("jump.mp3"));

...

public static void load() {

    music.setVolume(0.5f);
    music.setLooping(true);
    music.play();

    play = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("buttons/play.png"));
...
```

Music is playing all the time in loop. Sounds are initialized in specific situation from other part of game for example jump.

```
 @Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    Gdx.app.log("GameScreen", "resizing");
}

@Override
public void show() {
    Gdx.app.log("GameScreen", "show called");
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    Gdx.app.log("GameScreen", "hide called");
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    Gdx.app.log("GameScreen", "pause called");

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    Gdx.app.log("GameScreen", "resume called");


}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // Leave blank
}
```

Comment: Include your code, specially the part where you initialize your game and the back button.

Comment: I don't have any code to handle back button. All game works ok only sounds and music are missing after using android back button.

Comment: include your `pause()` method and `resume()` one, what do you do there?

Comment: Basilicaty my game run pause() when click on home button on android but when I click back button starts pause() and hide(). I think there is a problem? When screen is back no sound and game back to MenuScreen not to GameScreen.

Comment: I add 'if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.BACK)){
            Gdx.app.exit();
        }' to my render() in MenuScreen class. Still the same problem when back button is clicked game exit after run again no sounds??

Comment: try pause manually your music in the `pause()` method then resume it in the `resume()` method.

Comment: It doesn't help. I have to remove game from foregraund (life cycle) and start again to run sounds.

Comment: try one thing. after you press back, remove game from ram by cleaning ur memory. if it solves your problem then remove assetLoader.dispose

Comment: The problem is that your sound/music objects are static, which causes problems. Since you already use an asset manager, why not load the sounds/music with it? It should solve your problem.